# Count the occurrence of a particular string from a matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
[1] "B/A" "A/A" "B/A" "B/A" "B/B" "B/B" "B/B" "B/B" "A/A" "B/A" "B/B" "A/A" "B/A" "B/A" "B/A"
 [16] "B/B" "B/A" "B/B" "B/B" "B/A" "B/B" "B/B" "B/A" "B/A" "B/A" "B/B" "B/B" "B/B" "B/B" "A/A"
 [31] "B/B" "B/B" "B/A" "B/B" "B/A" "B/A" "B/B" "A/A" "B/A" "B/A" "B/A" "B/B" "B/B" "B/B" "B/A"
```

I want to count the occurrence of "B/A", "A/A", and "B/B" from each cell and put it in a new matrix. If "B/A" was detected then the count would be one in that cell of the matrix, if "A/A" was detected then count would be two, and if "B/B" was be 0.

So basically, the new matrix would look like:

```
[1] 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 1 ... so on 
[16] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ...
```

I would make a matrix where the
In attempt of doing so, my code looks like this:

```
count <- 0
for(i in dim(matrix1)[1])
{
  if(snp1 == "B/A")
    count = count + 1
}
print(count)
```

However, I get this output error:

```
Warning message:
In if (snp1 == "B/A") count = count + 1 :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You'll probably want to go through an R tutorial. Inside the body of your loop over `i`, you should use `i` somewhere, maybe like `snp1[i, ]`. Also, you need `i in seq_len(dim(matrix1)[1])` according to R's for-loop syntax.

Comment: You should edit the question and title. It sounds like what you want to do is substitute numbers for strings, not count the strings. Also your example matrix looks like a vector.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
# Generate data
alleles <- c("B/B", "B/A", "A/A")
genotype <- matrix(sample(alleles, 20, replace = TRUE), 5)

#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] 
# [1,] "B/B" "A/A" "B/A" "A/A"
# [2,] "B/B" "A/A" "A/A" "B/B"
# [3,] "A/A" "A/A" "B/B" "B/A"
# [4,] "B/A" "B/B" "B/A" "A/A"
# [5,] "B/B" "B/A" "B/A" "B/A"

genotypeQuant <- matrix(as.numeric(factor(genotype, levels = alleles)) - 1,
                        nrow = nrow(genotype))

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    2    1    2
# [2,]    0    2    2    0
# [3,]    2    2    0    1
# [4,]    1    0    1    2
# [5,]    0    1    1    1
```

First convert your matrix (alleles/SNPs) into factors (order provided in vector `alleles`) and then convert those factors into numbers.

Comment: @KatZee Can you please accept solution if it solved your problem

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your vector with "A/A", "B/A" and "B/B" is called `df`, I would just use:

```
df[df=="B/B"] <- 0
df[df=="B/A"] <- 1
df[df=="A/A"] <- 2
df <- as.numeric(df)
```

As long as you really only have these three unique values, this solution would do the trick.